# In CMake, is it possible to build a dependency imported from a build tree?

Tags: cmake, build-process, build-automation

I am trying to use the CMake feature for exporting/importing targets from a build tree (see [this wiki page](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets#Exporting_from_a_Build_Tree)). I have this `dependency` library:

```
add_library(dependency SHARED dependency.cpp)
export(TARGETS dependency FILE dependency-targets.cmake)
```

And an executable uses this library in another project:

```
include(${DEPENDENCY_PATH}/dependency-targets.cmake)

add_executable(main-app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main-app dependency)
```

This works fine. While I do understand that this export/import mechanism "only" provide a convenient way to reference external binaries, I am wondering whether `dependency` could be compiled when running `make` in `main-app`? Either using the import mechanism (which I doubt) or using another one ?

Answer (score 1):

You could look into the "superbuild" pattern and [ExternalProject](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#module%3aExternalProject).

The gist of the idea is that you set up one "superbuild" project which will use just `ExternalProject_Add()` commands; this will set up your real project and all its dependencies.

Comment: Actually, ExternalProject seems to build dependency the first time only; I still have to find out how to automatically rebuild dependency if some sources of dependency changes... Any idea? Thanks,